# Sorting table by clicking on cell in another table

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I have two HTML tables. One contains only the header cells, the other has the data. I have it this way so the header row remains in place while scrolling the data table.

How can I sort the data table by clicking the header table? I want to click the cell in the header table and have the *other* table sort by the same column.

I assume this will require Javascript.

Comment: Always remember to Google first! A query even for your question title `sorting table head in two html tables` will get you a lot of great results, including a ready-made jQuery plugin.

Comment: Why in the name of Goku would you have 2 tables for this? Have you ever heard of `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags?

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a table header fixed in place without placing it into a separate table. In fact, this is required if you want someone with a screenreader to be able to actually navigate the table.

Check out [jQuery.floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) - does exactly what you are looking for. [See Demo here](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/#examples).

Comment: I agree, this is the best plugin in the world. Written by a genius.

Comment: Ha! And a modest genius at that... But it is a seriously good plug-in, you did a nice job on that one.